# Method code depending on value of Instance?

Tags: java, android, class, interface, command-pattern

I have a question for Android (Java).

Lets say i have a list of commands (each one with command name, and execute method).
The execute method has different code depending on the command name (i.e. Command "GET GPS LOCATION" -> execute Method returns Location value).

So, I could use a single Command class with a switch-case in the execute method checking the name of the command and executing the code.
Or make a class for every command (which is not the best way i guess, because i have 80+ commands).
Or should i use an interface?
Or is there a better way at all?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the names of your commands follow a strict naming convention, you can use reflection to call the corresponding method. It spares you the big switch case. But personnally, a switch case seems more robust.

Comment: Yes, the commands follow a **strict naming** convention. Using a switch case was my first thought too, but this would require to define a special return type for the method, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java8, you can use [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to do this in a concise way :

```
public class Test {

  Map<String, Runnable> map = Maps.newHashMap();
  map.put("foo", Test::foo);
  map.put("bar", Test::bar);

  public static void foo() {

  }


  public static void bar() {

  }
}
```

Then, calling `map.get(methodName).run()` is enough.

Comment: This would be pretty much perfect for my case! I only see the one problem in the java version. Is there a similar way running with an older version? But thanks btw.

Comment: As the value of the Map is a Runnable, it is still possible to write the Runnable explicitly : `map.put("foo", new Runnable() { public void run() {foo()});`.

Comment: I just checked your solution and it was working fine in Java. To get it working for Android (not Java 8), i used this `map.put("foo", this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo"));` and replaced every `runnable` with `Method`. I guess this solution is a proper way too? @Arnaud Denoyelle

Answer (score 0):

How about you make an abstract Command class and use a map to retrieve the correct command, for example:

```
abstract class Command<T>
{
    public static final Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

    public Command(final String executeCommand)
    {
        commands.put(executeCommand, this);
    }

    public abstract T execute();
}
```

Then implemented with:

```
class LocationCommand extends Command<LocationValue>
{
    public LocationCommand()
    {
        super("GET GPS LOCATION");
    }

    @Override
    public LocationValue execute()
    {
        System.out.println("Getting GPS location");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you could retrieve them like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new LocationCommand();
    Command.commands.get("GET GPS LOCATION").execute(); //Output: Getting GPS location
}
```

Comment: This seams to be a quite neat solution too! But i wanted to stay independent of return types and stuff.